# netrw keeps hidding dotfiles while FTP connection in VIM

Tags: vim, ftp, dotfiles

I have to show the hidden files and directories (files and directories beginning with `.`) in netrw through FTP.

In a local environment, I can toggle hidden items with `gh` but through the FTP connection, it does not show/hide them. It keeps them hidden.

I looked for any solution through Google or `:help netrw` and even [in the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html) but without any success.

The question is : how to show dotfiles in netrw tree view from a remote directory ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a long-time user of vim and its plug-ins, you may be aware that netrw has a fair number of bugs. After some searching around the webs, it turns out that tree-view is -- apparently -- a feature that is [only little used](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/22ztqp/why_does_nerdtree_exist_whats_wrong_with_netrw/) *(who knew?)*

To answer your question: `gh` does not currently work with tree-view over FTP. Even if you have become familar with using netrw, I would advise you to begin moving on to another tool with a better API.

But don't give up! Do not lose heart! There are a few options:

- Try [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), also has the benefit of being updated slightly more recently than early 2014
- Try [vimfiler](https://github.com/Shougo/vimfiler.vim), Powerful file explorer implemented by Vim script
- Maybe even [vinegar.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar): combine with netrw to create a delicious salad dressing
- If all else fails, [please report any bugs to NdrOchip@ScampbellPfamily.AbizM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075)

**Long live Vim!**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'like to keep Vim simple and use native solution most but you're right there are better solutions.

Comment: How to browse remote folders with NERDTree ? It seems that only netrw can do that. Tried VimFiler as default explorer, but the command `:e ftp://domain.com/` still open in netrw.

Comment: Same result with vinegar. = S